# huge HTML lists from JSON performance issue

Tags: javascript, performance

i'm buildig a kind of project management tool using PHP on server side and jQuery plus a custom MVC in javascript.

I have a popup to help a user to add people on a project. Where it pops up, the user have to select a group (let's say a students group), and then he can pick profiles to add them in the current project.

I have tested it with groups of 70-120 persons and it works, with a little latency.

BUT WHEN I TEST A BIG GROUP OF 1,000 PERSONS, the refresh time is so long that Chrome asks me if I want to stop the script or wait more time... It's not nice for iser experience !!!

Data comes from server in JSON format :

{"users": [ { "uid" : "cortes", "firstname" : "Francois", "lastname" : "CORTES", "mail" : "..." } ], /* 1000 user records more */ }

and the data is formatted in this HTML (custom pseudo Mustache template)

```
<li>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p class="title"> {{firstname}} {{lastname}} {{mail}} </p>
    <p> {{uid}} </p>
    <p> <input type="checkbox" id="select-{{uid}}" /> </p>
  </div>
</li>
```

jQuery is used to build the list and add some listeners 
- select / unselect state local storing before popup validation
- a kind of highlight on hovering mouse
on each list element
[code][code]
My question is HOW TO TRACK PERFORMANCE LEAK and HOW TO FIX IT ?

Of course the code is a bit ugly and hard to maintain, and of course again I hava to fix this roblem quicly ... could someone help me ?

EDIT : Thanks for your comments and your posts.

A bit more explainations : usually groups hold 50-200 persons. The group of 1,000 persons is just the merge of 90% of the total, temporary and due to some technical and management reasons. But It's a great challenge to enforce performances and ensuring the reactivity of the UI.

For the moment it fails the test...

@Chris : I'm building a test controller in PHP to time the JSON generation and size

@Dandavis : Yes, for the moment I do this. I grab a generic DIV template from the page with jQuery, and loop 1,000 times over the JSON data, javascript string replacing wildcards {{example-data-name}} with its example-data-value, next I insert it into the DOM  (jQuery) and then I bind the event listeners (jQuery too)... Ugly code, I agree, but home-made, and no way and no time to refactor it using BackBone or Knockout...

documentFragment ? well... need to dig further more !

@ajax81 : static JSON cached at page load ??? why not... perhaps the simpliest way to modify existing work and effort !

@Alberto : useful tips I keep in mind. As I commented above, I start my tests this afternoon

My feeling is that PHP do its job correctly (regarding data size and generation speed), but m custom templating approach isn't efficient to handle the whole data !

No need to paginate data because user usually scrolls in a small (50) to medium (120) records list. The 1,000 is a stress test. It occurs only in summer period (holidays), but if I would success, user daily experiency will be better and secured against crashes on low performance systems.

Regards.

**EDIT and solving the issue**

*PHP*

I have benchmarked thz PHP script : 1,000 records extraction and JSON generation is less than 0.25 seconds execution time and less than 100ko long... so no particular problem server-side.

I have make some optimizations server-side to limit database and LDAP requesting by using some in-PHP caching, just to limit redundancies and network traffic from my app.

*Javascript*

Then I have modified templating usage : now I loop of 1,000 JSON records, evaluating template and appending result in a raw HTML string, next attaching LI elements to the UL.

At this point this list is visually ready for the user.

Later I loop again on JSON data to bind event handlers (click on  checkbox, click on surrounding DIV, and hovering that DIV with pointer...), but the list is yet displayed !

Latency at refreshing list is visible, but very brief, less than 1.5 seconds... Maybe I will add some hourglass icon to prevent user for repetitive clicks while waiting the list.

**so timing test now success**
In a regular use, lists won't exceed 150 persons, so if it's OK for 1,000 ... it's OK for me :-)

Thanks a lot (@all) for helping.

Comment: Have you timed the actual GET request for the person data to determine if the issue is transmitting the list?

Comment: hmm. templating is very quick, be it 12 or 12,000. are you appending/.html()ing 1,000 LI tags in a loop? if so, switch to a temp document.createDocumentFragment() and enjoy orders of magnitude better performance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly what you want, but are you using pagination in this json list?  List the values with pagination 10, 20, 30 rows etc, and give the ajax server call to grab the next batch of paged rows.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would follow these steps:

1. track down the query that fetches your data and time it, if it takes a lot maybe it's just a missing index, or an inefficient query, but at this point you know where to point your finger
2. use a static version of that page, without making any server side call, simply put the JSON result in a file and load that, see how your code behaves
3. as @Chris Pitman said how much time does the GET take

You should be able to roughly find where the problem is by following this steps.

As a general rule I would advice you to increase the number of letters at which the search starts, so that you will never return a lot of result, thus reducing load times, also because no one expects you to return results when the user enters "a" in the search field.

Another thing that you might want to evaluate is passing a thinner array, containing just the email of the users, fetching more data when requested, an email is unique by definition.

Comment: In my experience, Chrome doesn't usually prompt for cancellation while the file is being downloaded - its usually processing large amounts of data (post download) that triggers the warning. I'm not saying you didn't highlight great opportunities for optimization, but I don't think they are directly applicable to OP's exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not directly related to a "performance leak" tracking, because you know where the problem is and you've already identified the culprit: you're processing a gargantuan amount of data.  Alberto's suggestion for passing a thinner array and trying to do more with less is a great place to start. Ase Ena's suggestion to page your data is obvious but (I'm guessing) a little outside your comfort zone.

If this list of people is frequently accessed and used a lot throughout your application, Alberto's suggestion for caching the list in its own JSON file is a good one.  This will save you a hefty database query every time the list is needed and relieve you of having to make subsequent ajax calls to retrieve the data.  Plus, it will be cached on your client's machine (even across visits to the app) and improve performance because it won't have to be downloaded every single time they visit the app or every time the list needs to be displayed.  As an added bonus, caching the entire list on the client greatly simplifies the paging mechanism that you'll use to turn through the data, because you won't have to manage the server-side SQL, session state, etc.

Edit -

It occurred to me that you might not know what I mean when I say "cache the JSON file on the client".  Here's an example:

```
<script src="MyPeopleList.json?v1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You essentially just link in the json file the same way as any other javascript. Your JSON user list is now available to the rest of your application, and cached as well.  If you need to refresh the list or make sure that your users get the latest and greatest version of the list, you can simply change the "v1" to "v2".  (the version-ing is important because some flavors of Internet Explorer aggressively cache these files and won't refresh even if the file on the server is newer than the one in the cache).